# X=(Y-A)(Z+B) is it possible to figure X,Y, and Z if only A and B are known

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, arithmetic

Given the following formula.

```
1,000,000 = 1,000 x 1,000
```

If I was to subtract A from one of the values I get B in return for example.

```
1,000,000 = (1,000 - 800)(1,000 + 4,000)
```

or even more results

```
1,000,000 = (1,000 - 750)(1,000 + 3,000) = (1,000 - 500)(1,000 + 1,000)
```

If this is expressed as a formula X=(Y-A)(Z+B) and I knew the A and B values is it possible to figure our the XYZ values? such as

```
X = (Y - 750)(Z + 3,000) = (Y - 500)(Z + 1,000)
```

Comment: Well just take $Y, Z=0$ and $X$ equal to the right hand side. This shows that your question can always be solved, but is this really what you're looking for? Try to be more precise here.

Comment: Hi  @Saegusa, Im trying to figure out if there is a formula to solve X,Y and Z, in the last line. I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @JayWilliams Saegusa means that there is always a trivial solution, to set some of the values to zero. But that's probably not what you want. Maybe you want a unique, non-trivial solution? That could be trickier ...

Comment: Do the values need to be integers or do you want to include all real numbers? Perhaps only positive values? If you include all real numbers, even when you fix A, B and X for good measure, there are still infinitely many solutions. For example the equation $60=(3-A)(6-B)$ has infinitely many solutions for $A$ and $B$ as it represents a curve in the $AB$-plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with only one or two different pairs $A,B$.

Your final equation is equivalent to $X=YZ-750Z+3000Y-2250000=YZ-500Z+1000Y-500000$. Neglecting $X$ for the moment, we have $2000Y=250Z+1750000$. There are lots of (infinitely many) pairs $Y,Z$ which satisfy this, for example $Z=40,Y=880$ or $Z=120, Y=890$.

For each of these, the two expressions $(Y-750)(Z+3000)$ and $(Y-500)(Z+1000)$ are equal to each other, and you can just take their common value to be $X$. Here we have
$$395200=(880-750)(40+3000)=(880-500)(40+1000)\\
436800=(890-750)(120+3000)=(890-500)(120+1000)$$

If you had *three* expressions instead of just two, these would yield simultaneous equations for $Y$ and $Z$ which will usually only have one solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you started

> Given the following formula.
>
> 1,000,000 = 1,000 x 1,000
>
> If I was to subtract A from one of the values I get B in return for example.
>
> 1,000,000 = (1,000 - 800)(1,000 + 4,000)

What you really did was provide values for $A, X, Y,$ and $Z$ and then solve for $B$. Yes, you can do that. But, if you want $B$ to be an integer, only certain values of $A, X, Y,$ and $Z$ will work.

Mathematically, it would look like this

\begin{align}
   X &= (Y-A)(Z+B) \\
   \dfrac{X}{(Y-A)} &= Z-B \\
   \dfrac{X}{(Y-A)}-Z &= -B \\
   Z - \dfrac{X}{(Y-A)} &= B
\end{align}

The rest of your question confuses me.

> or even more results
>
> X = (Y-A)(Z + B) = (Y - A')(Z + B')
>
> If this is expressed as a formula X=(Y-A)(Z+B) and I knew the A and B values
> is it possible to figure our the XYZ values? such as
>
> X = (Y - 750)(Z + 3,000) = (Y - 500)(Z + 1,000)
>
> If **this** is expressed as a formula X=(Y-A)(Z+B) and I knew the A and B values

By **this** I think you meant the expressions

> 1,000,000 = (1,000 - 750)(1,000 + 3,000) = (1,000 - 500)(1,000 + 1,000)

where you clearly provided values for $X, Y,$ and $Z$. and found two solutions $(A, B) = (750, 3000)$ and $(A, B) = (500, 1000)$. There could be other solutions, but I didn't try to find them.

I can't give an exact answer, but, yes, some of the time you can assign values to some of the variables and then find one or more solutions for the remaining variables. The number of solutions you find depends on your domain - the set of numbers that you will draw your solutions from. Like integers, postive integers, fractions, or real numbers.

### Added 9/21/2021

$$ X = (Y-A)(Z + B)$$

If you are given $A$ and $B$, and you have picked a particular value of $X$...

Find a pair of integers, say $U$ and $V$ for which $UV = X$. Then $Y=U+A$ and $Z = V-B$.

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for replying. I'm a software coder not mathematician so sorry if I'm wording it incorrectly. The software will generate random keypairs (positive integers), for A and B. A and B are calculated following the expression above. So the output of the software will be (800,4000),(750,3000), (500,1000) and so on for as many requests I make. I am trying to now find a formula which will give XYZ from the AB keypairs. In the example above I know XYZ, but if I didnt know XYZ and only knew the formula and values for AB, I am trying to figure out a formula to find the values for XYZ.Thnks